# SVG gaussian blur filter causing an unexpected greenish glow

Tags: svg, blur, svg-filters

Yello!

I have a strange occurence when using a gaussian blur filter on an SVG text element in Firefoxy. I tried searching the web for solutions but I haven't even been able to find anything mentioning this issue. Here's a reproducible example (and the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68eER/)):

```
<svg id="svg1" width="100%" height="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

    <defs>
        <filter id="filterBlur">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" result="blurOut" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" />
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <text class="link" x="100" y="100">Hello World</text>

</svg>
```

And the CSS

```
body {background-color:black;}

text {
    font-family: "Arial";
    fill: white;
}

.link {
    font-size: 20px;
    opacity: 0.90;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    filter: url(#filterBlur);
}
```

I have tried several fonts but they all exhibit the same greenish glow. In Chrome the blur works just fine. Any ideas?

D

Comment: looks ok on Mac OS - if that's any consolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [fix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=812795) for this is coming in Firefox 29. You can download the [beta](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/beta/) now if you want to try it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any other way to use blur on SVG text elements?

Comment: I suspect any other ways would suffer from the same green glow.